# How to add 5 second delay to onClick window.open?

Tags: jquery, onclick, delay, window.open

I have a code that hides multiple div's with a sliding action with one click on a text link.
I need to add an open.window to the text link also, that will open a url in another window after a few seconds delay.

So with one click I want to hide a group of div's, and open a url in another window after a short delay, so that the sliding action can be seen before the url is opened.

I have this code that works to hide the div's with sliding action ...

```
$("#hide-content").click(function () {
$(".otherContainers").hide('slide',{direction: "right"}, 1000);
});
```

And this for the text link ....

```
<div id="hide-content"><a href="#" class="showHideContent" style="text-decoration:none" onclick="window.open('http://google.com')">hide and visit</a>
</div>
```

I've tried adding a delay with this but it's not working ...

```
onclick="setTimeout('window.open(\'http://google.com');'5000;"
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Here's a Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/eeyipes/Jf6wM/13/

Comment: Your setTimeout function is missing an ending bracket...

Comment: A window is only opened if it originated from a user action. Deferring the window open with a timeout could cause some browsers to block the window, all though I haven't really tested it.

Comment: I haven't tested this exhaustively, but it appears browsers do indeed block the window if the timeout is 1001 ms or greater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parenthese and quotes aren't balanced. Try:

```
onclick="setTimeout('window.open(\'http://google.com\')', 5000);"
```